# A script for making another script deal with all files in sequence?

Tags: shell-script

I have found a nicely working script to convert pdf files into txt format, with ocr.

But it converts only one pdf file each time. I need to mass-convert them.

I have no knowledge of script writing. The script is at below.

How can I mass convert them?

```
#!/bin/bash

## script to:
##   *  split a PDF up by pages
##   *  convert them to an image format
##   *  read the text from each page
##   *  concatenate the pages


## pass name of PDF file to script
INFILE=$1

## split PDF file into pages, resulting files will be
## numbered: pg_0001.pdf  pg_0002.pdf  pg_0003.pdf
pdftk $INFILE burst

for i in pg*.pdf ; do

    ## convert it to a PNG image file
    convert -density 200 -quality 100 $i ${i%.pdf}.png

    ## read text from each page
    tesseract ${i%.pdf}.png ${i%.pdf}.txt

done

## concatenate the pages into a single text file
cat pg*.txt > ${INFILE%.pdf}.txt

exit
```

Note: I have read the similar questions but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could modify your script:

```
# instead of INFILE=$1
for INFILE
do
#...

    for i in pg*.pdf ; do
        #...    
    done

    ## concatenate the pages into a single text file
    cat pg*.txt > ${INFILE%.pdf}.txt
done
```

Then call your script thus:

```
some-script.sh 1.pdf 2.pdf #...
```

A `bash` `for` loop, when not given anything to loop on, loops over all the command-line arguments. Hence,

```
for INFILE
```

is equivalent to:

```
for INFILE in "$@"
```

Comment: Thanks! here:
http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=55341&p=555710#p555710

I think YAGF, the Linux ocr GUI is very slow, it converts to TIFF, and if they use this technique, Abbyy Fine Reader is dead!

Answer (score 1):

From what i understand from your question, i guess this is what you expect:

```
for each in *.pdf
do
  your_conv_script.sh $each
done
```

where `your_conv_script.sh` is the script that you have denoted above.

Also note that you need to clean temporarily created files.